Distribution of the Distance between Quadratic Roots

Choose $b,c$ uniformly and independently on the interval $[-1, 1]$. Consider the roots $r_1, r_2$ of the quadratic equation $f(x) = x^2 + bx + c$. What is the distribution that describes the euclidean distance between the two roots on the complex plane?

From the quadratic equation, we have $r_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2}(-b \pm\sqrt{b^2 - 4c})$. The euclidean distance between two complex numbers is the magnitude of the difference between the two. Thus, the length of the segment between the two roots, in terms of $a,b$, is simply the magnitude of the square root of the discriminant, $|\sqrt {b^2 - 4c}|$. However, I do not know how to proceed with calculating the distribution of values formed by inputting randomly chosen $b,c \in [-1, 1]$ into this expression.
The histogram below shows the euclidean distance $d$ between the two roots of $x^2 + bx + c$, with uniformly selected $b, c \in [-1, 1]$ after $10000$ iterations. The aim of this question is to determine the distribution outlined in blue. In the limiting case, as the number of iterations grows, the distribution is skew left, and seems to grow linearly until around $d \approx 1.8$, with a sharp decline afterwards.
The mean, mode, and median are approximately $1.3376883617075928, 1.7909208304644033, 1.4120368146176268$. I suspect the true median of the distribution will be $\sqrt 2$. I am happy to provide more information, statistical descriptions if needed.

Thanks.

In general if you know the density of a random variable $X$, you also know the density of $Y=f(X)$. See here.
Define $f:[-1,+1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ as:
$$ f(x) = [\frac{-x_1 + \sqrt{x_1^2 - 4x_2}}{2}  \ \quad \frac{-x_1 - \sqrt{x_1^2 - 4x_2}}{2} ]^T $$
You can think the domain of $f$ to be pairs of $(b,c)$ and the range to be the pairs of roots. Now we know:
$$ p(Y) = det(J_{f^{-1}}(Y)) p(X=f^{-1}(Y))$$
Where $J_{f^{-1}}$ is the Jacobian matrix of inverse of $f$.
We know $c$ is multiplication of the roots and $b$ is negative of the sum of roots. So
$$ f^{-1}(Y) = [-y_1-y_2 \quad y_1 y_2]^T $$
$$ J_{f^{-1}}(Y) = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1\\
Y_2 & Y_1
\end{bmatrix} $$
$$  |det(J_{f^{-1}}(Y))| = Y_1-Y_2 $$
Combining everything we get:
$$ p(Y) = 
\begin{cases}
Y_1-Y_2 & Y_1 \geq Y_2 
        \land -1 \leq Y_1+Y_2 \leq 1
        \land -1 \leq Y_1 Y_2 \leq 1 \\
0 &o.w.
\end{cases}
$$
